# How to break numpy array into smaller chunks/batches, then iterate through them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose i have this numpy array

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[10, 11, 12]]
```

And i want to split it in 2 batches and then iterate:

```
[[1, 2, 3],      Batch 1
[4, 5, 6]]

[[7, 8, 9],      Batch 2
[10, 11, 12]]
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

EDIT: **I'm deeply sorry i missed putting such info**: Once i intend to carry on with the iteration, the original array would be destroyed due to splitting and iterating over batches. Once the batch iteration finished, i need to restart again from the first batch hence **I should preserve that the original array wouldn't be destroyed**. The whole idea is to be consistent with Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithms which require iterations over batches. In a typical example, I could have a 100000 iteration For loop for just 1000 batch that should be replayed again and again.

Comment: and then iterate? do you mean you want to split Batch 1 and Batch 2 into smaller batches still?

Comment: @benten yes, pick the first batch from the original array and then iterate to the second batch after.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

consider array `a`

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12]])
```

***Option 1***
use `reshape` and `//`

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0] // 2, -1, a.shape[1])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

***Option 2***
if you wanted groups of two rather than two groups

```
a.reshape(-1, 2, a.shape[1])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

***Option 3***
Use a generator

```
def get_every_n(a, n=2):
    for i in range(a.shape[0] // n):
        yield a[n*i:n*(i+1)]

for sa in get_every_n(a, n=2):
    print sa

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split along the first axis `n` times, where `n` is the number of desired batches. Thus, the implementation would look like this -

```
np.split(arr,n,axis=0) # n is number of batches
```

Since, the default value for `axis` is `0` itself, so we can skip setting it. So, we would simply have -

```
np.split(arr,n)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [132]: arr  # Input array of shape (10,3)
Out[132]: 
array([[170,  52, 204],
       [114, 235, 191],
       [ 63, 145, 171],
       [ 16,  97, 173],
       [197,  36, 246],
       [218,  75,  68],
       [223, 198,  84],
       [206, 211, 151],
       [187, 132,  18],
       [121, 212, 140]])

In [133]: np.split(arr,2) # Split into 2 batches
Out[133]: 
[array([[170,  52, 204],
        [114, 235, 191],
        [ 63, 145, 171],
        [ 16,  97, 173],
        [197,  36, 246]]), array([[218,  75,  68],
        [223, 198,  84],
        [206, 211, 151],
        [187, 132,  18],
        [121, 212, 140]])]

In [134]: np.split(arr,5) # Split into 5 batches
Out[134]: 
[array([[170,  52, 204],
        [114, 235, 191]]), array([[ 63, 145, 171],
        [ 16,  97, 173]]), array([[197,  36, 246],
        [218,  75,  68]]), array([[223, 198,  84],
        [206, 211, 151]]), array([[187, 132,  18],
        [121, 212, 140]])]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really like the Split idea, however i forgot to mention that i need to preserve the original array to stay intact and not be destroyed by batching. I updated my question with those details. Anyway, I'll get to work on your suggestion and let you know the results.

Comment: @Leb_Broth Well the original array isn't destroyed. So, if you do : `out = np.split(arr,n)`, we would have a list of such batches as arrays in the list `out` and `arr` unchanged. Does that clarify your concerns?

Comment: ah yes sorry u'r totally right. I forgot about that. I can just save a value of the original between the first 'while iteration < 100000' and the inner 'For i in batch' loop. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there anyway to pre-allocated memory for the split arrays and then fill them in?  Instead of two arrays, say 4.

Comment: @Merlin If memory is a concern, I would suggest going with a reshape method and then index into each element at the first axis to have the same effect as this splitting. This is what the other answer by @ piRSquared achieves.

Comment: I love it when I finally see an answer you've posted next to one of mine years later (-;

Answer (score 7):

To avoid the error "array split does not result in an equal division",

```
np.array_split(arr, n, axis=0)
```

is better than `np.split(arr, n, axis=0)`.

For example,

```
a = np.array([[170,  52, 204],
              [114, 235, 191],
              [ 63, 145, 171],
              [ 16,  97, 173]])
```

then

```
print(np.array_split(a, 2))

[array([[170,  52, 204],
       [114, 235, 191]]), array([[ 63, 145, 171],
       [ 16,  97, 173]])]

print(np.array_split(a, 3))

[array([[170,  52, 204],
       [114, 235, 191]]), array([[ 63, 145, 171]]), array([[ 16,  97, 173]])]
```

However, `print(np.split(a, 3))` will raise an error since `4/3` is not an integer.

Comment: See the `print(np.array_split(a, 3))` example, that "leftovers" are placed in front. Try `np.array_split(np.random.random((17, 2)), 7)` for better understanding. This is useful if you want to limit batch size. So, you need to use `(nrows/batchsize)+1` to find `nbatches`.

Answer (score 2):

Improving previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592397/11671779), to split based on batch size, you can use:

```
def split_by_batchsize(arr, batch_size):
    return np.array_split(arr, (arr.shape[0]/batch_size)+1)
```

or with extra safety:

```py
def split_by_batch_size(arr, batch_size):
    nbatches = arr.shape[0]//batch_size
    if nbatches != arr.shape[0]/batch_size:
        nbatches += 1
    return np.array_split(arr, nbatches)
```

example:

```py
import numpy as np


ncols = 17
batch_size= 2

split_by_batchsize(np.random.random((ncols, 2)), batch_size)
# [array([[0.60482079, 0.81391257],
#         [0.00175093, 0.25126441]]),
#  array([[0.48591974, 0.77793401],
#         [0.72128946, 0.3606879 ]]),
#  array([[0.95649328, 0.24765806],
#         [0.78844782, 0.56304567]]),
#  array([[0.07310456, 0.76940976],
#         [0.92163079, 0.90803845]]),
#  array([[0.77838703, 0.98460593],
#         [0.88397437, 0.39227769]]),
#  array([[0.87599421, 0.7038426 ],
#         [0.19780976, 0.12763436]]),
#  array([[0.14263759, 0.9182901 ],
#         [0.40523958, 0.0716843 ]]),
#  array([[0.9802908 , 0.01067808],
#         [0.53095143, 0.74797636]]),
#  array([[0.7596607 , 0.97923229]])]
```

Sadly, simple iteration is faster than this fancy method. Thus, I did not suggest you to use this approach.

```
batch_size = 3
nrows = 1000

arr = np.random.random((nrows, 2))

%%timeit
for i in range((arr.shape[0] // batch_size) + 1):
    idx = i*batch_size
    foo = arr[idx:idx+batch_size,:]
# 345 µs ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
for foo in split_by_batch_size(arr, batch_size):
    pass
# 1.84 ms ± 377 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The speed different seems came from `np.array_split` create list of array first.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used to iterate through. I use `b.next()` method to generate the indices, then pass the output to slice a numpy array, for example `a[b.next()]` where a is a numpy array.

```
class Batch():    
    def __init__(self, total, batch_size):
        self.total = total
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.current = 0

    def next(self):
        max_index = self.current + self.batch_size
        indices = [i if i < self.total else i - self.total 
                       for i in range(self.current, max_index)]
        self.current = max_index % self.total
        return indices 

b = Batch(10, 3)
print(b.next()) # [0, 1, 2]
print(b.next()) # [3, 4, 5]
print(b.next()) # [6, 7, 8]
print(b.next()) # [9, 0, 1]
print(b.next()) # [2, 3, 4]
print(b.next()) # [5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score -2):

do like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]]
b = a[0:2]
c = a[2:4]
```